# Without using ZoomFactor in ScrollViewer Can I receive only Pinch Zoom events in UWP

Tags: events, uwp, zooming

Without using ZoomFactor in ScrollViewer
Can I receive only Pinch ZoomIn, ZoomOut events?

ZoomFactor has a limited size limit
If Pinch Zoom event occurs without ZoomFactor
We are going to implement zooming with the RenderTransform.ScaleTransform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid ManipulationMode="Scale" ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDetla">...</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But if you do this, you'll turn off scrolling. You have to leave ScrollViewer's manipulation mode alone (Default: System) if you want it's low-latency interactivity. If you set your own manipulation, you're going to experience a painful lag.

If you want to handle all manipulation yourself, then include TranslateX/Y and anything else you feel comfortable programming.

Comment: All I want is to receive events only.
I do not want to zoom in due to the Pinch Zoom.

Comment: The above will turn off zooming and pass the events to you. Did you try the code above?

Comment: I've tried it, but no OnManipulationDelta event has occurred.

Comment: set ZoomMode = "Enabled" in ScrollViewer, it zooms in and out.

Comment: Try applying the `ManipulationMode` to the child of the `ScrollViewer`. I've updated my answer.